# Why Items not displayed in web part after CSR customization in SharePoint2013?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I tried to customize web part in SharePoint 2013 with CSR Javascript file, but after all changes in view I has items with text [object Object] instead normally List Items. What's can be a problem?

My JS code:

```
(function () {
/*
 * Initialize the variable that store the overrides objects.
 */
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

 // Assign functions or plain html strings to the templateset objects:


//  This template is assigned to the CustomItem function.
overrideCtx.Templates.Group = CustomGroup;
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

//       Register the template overrides.

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

 /*
 * This function builds the output for the item template.
 * Uses the Context object to access announcement data.
 */
function CustomItem(ctx) {
// Build a listitem entry for every announcement in the list.
var ret = '<div style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid #333; padding: 5px;"> <div> <div style="float: left; display: inline-block;">' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + 
'</div> <div style="float: right; display: inline-block;">' + ctx.CurrentItem.TaskDueDate + '</div> </div> <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">' + ctx.CurrentItem.CategoryDescription + '</div> </div>';
return ret;
};

function CustomGroup(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, expand) {
var html = '<div style="font-weight:bold; display: inline-block;">' + listItem[group] + ' ::'  + '<div><ul>'+listItem+ '</ul></div>' + '</div>';
return html;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of your variables contain objects instead of strings.  Here's a way to find out which ones.

Add some output trace to your javascript, between setting and returning your "ret" variable.  For example, in CustomItem you might add:

```
console.log("Title, Due Date, and Category are:);
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.TaskDueDate);
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.CategoryDescription);
```

Open your page and display the console using the browser. ([Chrome console instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console))

In the console, you'll see four lines of output for each item processed.  One of those will probably say [Object] instead of the string value you're looking for.
Click the triangle icon to the left of [Object] to expand the object's properties.

Now that you can see the object structure, adjust your "ret" variable to get the string value.  For example, it might be ctx.CurrentItem.CategoryDescription.Title instead of just ctx.CurrentItem.CategoryDescription